# Is it possible to include a string?

Tags: php

I mean, I have a string: `"class cl{...}"`, and I would like to include it. I know there is the `eval` function, but is it the best way to do it?

Comment: Don't do it! Eval is evil and every function (if there is one) providing similar function is evil too.

Comment: Why is that class definition in a string?

Comment: I cannot think of a single reason for doing that. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Also, include it where?

Comment: you can have dynamic classes without having to redefine a class with a specific name each time.  Look into magic class functions to learn how you can manipulate class behavior.

Comment: `include` performs eval on included file. There are 2 ways you can do what you described - put the string in a file and `include` it or `eval` the string. Third option, and in my opinion the best one - don't do either of mentioned, describe what problem you're solving and  approach it from a different angle. Your solution seems flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends why you have this as a string. Where does it come from?

If it is user generated, i.e. a user input, better not put it through eval. The user could easily run any code on your website!

If you read this from a file and know it is legitimate, just use `include` on that file. But you also could use `eval`. It is just important that that string is not user generated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to dynamically call object

```
namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test() {
        print "Hello world!\n";
    }
}

call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test'); // As of PHP 5.3.0
call_user_func(array(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo', 'test')); // As of PHP 5.3.0
```

In your case :

```
$obj = '\Foo';
$method = 'test';
call_user_func(array(__NAMESPACE__ .$obj, $method));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some sort of custom for PHP users to ask this kind of questions: to devise some unusual and unreliable mechanism, then get stuck with it and then come to Stack Overflow with a question. And we have a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with a smell of insecurity. And a smelly answer as well, as SO is strictly direct in it's answers.

Why you have to have it upside down: come with a question first, and then get the proper solution for your real problem.